# Bootstrap: How can I change the height of the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/Pabi/pen/bdmgjm
Here is my CSS:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------
  3.1 Topbar
---------------------------------------------------*/

#section-topbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: visible;
  font: normal 16px/24px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /*  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(232,235,237);*/
}
/*Makes it so when you hover over the icon stays white*/

#section-topbar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#section-topbar ul#nav > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

#section-topbar ul#nav a {
  display: block;
  font: normal 11px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 18px 20px 18px 20px;
}

#section-topbar ul#nav .menu-item-left a:hover {
  background: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#section-topbar ul#nav .active a {
  background: #44bbaa;
}

#section-topbar ul#nav .active a:hover {
  background: #44bbaa;
}

#section-topbar i {
  font-size: 25px;
}
/*Center Brand on NavBar*/

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

How can I change the height of the navbar to something that is thinner and possible make the dropdown text with a dropdown icon next to it instead of a button.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @Pabi, could you be more specific? You've used navbar-right in your ul class. Was it intentional? If you are not familiar with Bootstrap, check some original examples: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: you are having the codes wrong. Stick with examples and change the content as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be to use the Sass or Less source and change the default value for `$navbar-height`

The nice thing about this, is that all the other calculations for top and bottom margins or padding of navbar elements will automatically adjust based on the new value. It's a far more maintainable and clean solution than trying to override the compiled styles.

With regard to making the dropdown text instead of a button, see the example from the bootstrap docs of the dropdown in a navbar, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#default-navbar:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

You should be able to do something very similar inside of your `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the height of the topbar with smaller padding around the icons :

```
#section-topbar ul#nav a {
  ...
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```